# What does "wedge" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Tuttugu answered by burying the *wedge* of his blade in the man’s sternum.

Comment: It means whoever wrote that was not a careful writer.

Comment: Edge* probably.

Comment: @Robusto - There's nothing wrong with this usage.

Comment: @HotLicks: There's nothing particularly good about it either. As Twain said, "The difference between the right word and *almost* the right word is the difference between lightning and a lightning bug."

Comment: @Robusto - I'm guessing there were many things Twain wrote that would make you complain.

Comment: @HotLicks: Apparently you don't know anything about me.

Comment: Normally, if you stab someone (geesus, am I saying this???), the tip of the blade goes in first. If, on the other hand, you plant a blade in a different way, say cross-wise, it could be the wedge of the blade instead of its tip.

Comment: Also, the weapon (this is like a Viking-y thing) could be an axe: See them here: http://www.hurstwic.org/history/articles/manufacturing/text/viking_axe.htm Loads of wedges. After seeing The Vikings on the History Channel, this book seems like a pale imitation.

Comment: When I saw this was closed, all I could think of was **sour grapes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wedge](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wedge):

> A piece of wood, metal, or some other material having one thick end
> and tapering to a thin edge, that is driven between two objects or
> parts of an object to secure or separate them.

Comment: Yes, I know the definition but I couldn't figure out the connection between the "blade" and "wedge". Can you please clarify if you understand it?

Comment: @ppm - The usage is a hair poetic, and the precise meaning would vary depending on the nature of his blade.  But I would take it to mean "tip" or "edge".  Note that if, say, a dagger blade were jammed into a man's sternum, it would likely hit bone and would not penetrate deeply.

Comment: "the nature of his blade"-- all of the blades that I know how to use have a thick part whose purpose is to provide a more or less rigid structure (according to its purpose) for the cutting edge or point itself. That is, they're all wedge-shaped (in cross-section at least); what varies is the _angle_ of the wedge and it's shape close to the action.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like context to help one along....

The sentence is taken from **The Liar's Key by Mark Lawrence, a fantasy writer.**
If you google and read a few lines, the Nordic/Viking implication is clear.

*The trick is that usually one thinks of a tip of a sword rather than the wedge of an axe.*

The Vikings et alia used stone axes and metal axes of various kinds.

This book takes place in a Nordic scenario like that, real or imagined.

See [many wedges here](http://www.hurstwic.org/history/articles/manufacturing/text/viking_axe.htm)

[image: Viking axe]

From that same site, I just could not resist this image:

[image: http://www.hurstwic.org/history/articles/manufacturing/pix/axe_sheath.jpg]

Steve Carrell as Viking warrior? [That's a joke....]